# How to set listener correctly?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview

If there is an initializing of onItemClickListener with adapter view, how can I set setOnItemClickListener for list view correctly? I have following code and I have a mistake on the before and before last one string, where I try to `listView.setOnClickListener(itemClickListener);`

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_top_level);

    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listenView, View itemView, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(TopLevelActivity.this, DrinkCategoryActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_options);
    listView.setOnClickListener(itemClickListener);
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**why not try this instead of itemclicklistener:--**

```
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), destinationclass.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Comment: First one didn't works, it makes app crush every time, the second one works correctly though. Thank you!